# Changing controller values doesn't reflect on the components in other directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-components

I've been using a directive for the code below, with one controller containing all the DOM manipulating logic for it, I've been asked to convert it into a component and since the change, the changes in the controller carry through fine to the controller from a different component, but not the intented component, there's something wrong in the declaration below but I can't quite figure it out

```
angular.module('headers').component('headerMenu', {
    templateUrl: 'components/header/menu/menu.template.html',
    controller: require('./func/header.component')
});
```

The controller path is correct, I double checked and it compiles fine, but for the value changes doesn't reflect in the new components as it did in the old directives

Comment: There are some errors in console?

Comment: @SamuelRoberto None

Comment: Components use isolate scope. AngularJS expressions in the template will not inherit from outside scopes. Define one-way (`"<"`) bindings to connect parent scope properties to component isolate scope. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based application architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture).

Comment: @SamuelRoberto AngularJS expressions in templates are "forgiving", errors are silent and return empty values. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - AngularJS Expressions vs. JavaScript Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#angularjs-expressions-vs-javascript-expressions).

Comment: Controllers in components are instantiated with `controllerAs: $ctrl`. Template expressions should be prefixed with `$ctrl.` Component controllers should use the `this` property for setting Model values. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Comparison between Directive definition and Component definition](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#comparison-between-directive-definition-and-component-definition).